# Facebook posts pagination?

Tags: ios, facebook

I see that I can limit the number of posts returned from fbconnect. However, I cannot figure out how to page through the posts? For example I only return the first 25 for speed purposes. Then at the bottom of the user's tableview I place a load next 25 button and so on. How can I change @"platform/posts?limit=25" to include a start and end position of the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `offset` parameter. For example, `@"platform/posts?limit=25&offset=25`, and just keep track of how many times the load next 25 button is pressed.